# issue with fragment-to-fragment communication using viewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm new to Kotlin and android development but i can't find why my program isn't working.
I'm trying to be able to communicate from my first fragment to his child, and testing it with a string but it won't display.
Thanks in advance for your help !!!
My first fragment :

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel : Communicator

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(Communicator::class.java) // .of supprimé
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        viewModel.message.value = "test"
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_stall_selection).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my second :

```
class SecondFragment() : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel :Communicator
    private var msg: String? = ""
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(Communicator::class.java) // .of deleted
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

        viewModel.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            msg = viewModel.message.value
        })

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView_1).text = msg
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

and finally here is the viewModel class i'm trying to use in order to communicate :

```
import  androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import  androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class Communicator() : ViewModel(){

    val message =MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setMsgCommunicator(msg:String){
        message.setValue(msg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FirstFragment, try to call `viewModel.setMsgCommunicator("test")` instead of directly calling `viewModel.message.value = "test"`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried but after working more on it, I think that the issue is with passing the same instance of `Communicator`. In this script I re-create an instance of my viewModel instead of passing the same one between those fragments. But i don't know how to do this unfortanetly

Comment: Do these two fragments belong to the same activity? Are you 100% sure the viewmodel gets recreated and is not reused?